# Python selenium doesn't click

Tags: python, selenium, click

So I'm losing my mind over here. I want to click on a specific button but there is an error which I don't understand:

```js
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\leosc\PycharmProjects\ogameBot\guideline.py", line 22, in guideline
    if metalMineLVL() > (10):
  File "C:\Users\leosc\PycharmProjects\ogameBot\guideline.py", line 10, in <lambda>
    metalMineLVL = lambda: c.metalMine.checkLVL()
  File "C:\Users\leosc\PycharmProjects\ogameBot\classes.py", line 121, in checkLVL
    a = self.sparte()
  File "C:\Users\leosc\PycharmProjects\ogameBot\classes.py", line 54, in <lambda>
    (By.XPATH, ('//*[contains(text(),\'{}\')]').format(sparte))))
  File "C:\Users\leosc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 71, in until
    value = method(self._driver)
  File "C:\Users\leosc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\expected_conditions.py", line 64, in __call__
    return _find_element(driver, self.locator)
  File "C:\Users\leosc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\expected_conditions.py", line 415, in _find_element
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\leosc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\expected_conditions.py", line 411, in _find_element
    return driver.find_element(*by)
  File "C:\Users\leosc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\leosc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\leosc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchWindowException: Message: no such window: target window already closed
from unknown error: web view not found
  (Session info: chrome=72.0.3626.121)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628402 (536cd7adbad73a3783fdc2cab92ab2ba7ec361e1),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

Here the code:

```js
self.sparte = lambda: wait.until(                   
    EC.presence_of_element_located(
    (By.XPATH, ('//*[contains(text(),\'{}\')]').format(sparte))))
self.LVL = lambda: int(
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ('//* 
    [@ref=\'' + str(ref) + '\']/span/span')))).text)

def checkLVL(self):

    time.sleep(1)
    self.sparte().click()
    time.sleep(1)
    return self.LVL()


    metalMineLVL = lambda: c.metalMine.checkLVL()
    roboFabLVL = lambda: c.roboFab.checkLVL()

    try:
        if metalMineLVL() > (10):
            if roboFabLVL() <(5):
                c.roboFab.build()
    except:
        pass
```

When I activate the debugger I see that every thing is processed until it gets to

```
self.sparte = lambda: wait.until(                   
    EC.presence_of_element_located(
    (By.XPATH, ('//*[contains(text(),\'{}\')]').format(sparte))))
```

and then it goes to the exception part. BUT I use this line of code in the rest of the program all the time and usually it works perfectly. What do I do wrong?
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you get that error. My best guess is that it's because of namespace conflicts but I'm not sure. This is the code I use for clicking on things:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

def clickElement(driver, XP):
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, XP)))
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(XP).click()
```

Example:

```
clickElement(driver, '/html/body/div[3]/div/a[1]')
```

Also check out [PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) for string formating.

Answer (score 0):

I now found out that the problem was that the program opens 4 additional tabs and then closes the initial one. Normally, I then did:

```js
newTabs = c.driver.window_handles
        for tab in newTabs:
            c.driver.switch_to.window(tab)
```

to get Selenium working on the new tabs. Yet, writing the new code, I forgor to do so, so Selenium thought it's still operating on the initial tab, which was already closed.
Thanks a lot anyway!!